# make a vector with variable a linear combination

Tags: vector-spaces

I have this 3 vectors:

$\overrightarrow{u} = \{1,3,a\}$

$\overrightarrow{v} = \{1,-1,0\}$

$\overrightarrow{w} = \{2,1,1\}$

I need to find the 'a' in vector $\overrightarrow{u}$ such that $\overrightarrow{u}$ is a linear combination of $\overrightarrow{v}$ and $\overrightarrow{w}$.

What I tried:

Compute the determinant ( det(A) = 0 )
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0\\2&1&1\\1&3&a\end{pmatrix}$$

> I think than I did the matrix wrong...
>   I think the correcly is that way:
>   $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&2\\3&-1&1\\a&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
>   The $ Det(A) = {4\over{3}} $

$$
A = a+(-1)-(-3)-(-2a) \\
A = a+2+2a \\
A = 3a+2 \\
A = {-2\over{3}}
$$

ok, after this, I tried to make the linear equations:

$$
(1,3,a) = a(1,-1,0)+\beta(2,1,1) \\
(1,3,a) = (a,-a,0)+(2\beta,\beta,\beta) \\
(1,3,a) = (a+2\beta,-a+\beta,\beta) \\
$$

$\begin{cases} +a + 2\beta = 1 \\ -a + \beta = 3 \\  0 + \beta = a \end{cases}$

But, when I compute the a value, it's not the same of $\beta$

Comment: Your calculations are very confused. Do you know how compute a determinant?

Comment: yes, I know how to compute the determinant..., but I am suspicious that reversed things in the array ...

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

> $n$ vectors are linearly independent if the determinant of the matrix
>   that has such vector as columns or rows is $O$.

So your two matrices $A$ are all good.

The determinant is :
$$
\mbox{det}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0\\
2 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 3 & a
\end{bmatrix}
=1\cdot
\mbox{det}
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1\\
 3 & a
\end{bmatrix}
-(-1)\cdot
\mbox{det}
\begin{bmatrix}
2  & 1\\
1  & a
\end{bmatrix}=
a-3+2a-1=3a-4
$$
so you have
$3a-4=0 \Rightarrow a=\dfrac{4}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

Your linear system

$\alpha +2 \beta =1$

$-\alpha+\beta  =3$

$\beta =a$

is o.k.

Substitude $\beta =a$ in first and second equation,
then add:

$\alpha +2 a =1$

$-\alpha+a  =3$

So

$3 a =4$

and therefore

$a=\frac{4}{3}$